# AVD manager is not creating device

Tags: android

Hello I just installed ADT bundle which comes with eclipse Juno 4.2.0 and Android SDK. But when I am trying to create a virtual device in AVD manager the ok button stays grey.

1. I tried to clone it; the create button got selected but does nothing.
2. I tried to run AVDmanager.exe from tools/lib. I got

"Failed to execute tools\android,bat:. error 2.
The system can't find file specified."

1. copy the AVDmanager.exe to /sdk but it is still not working

I understand that may be I am doing some path setting wrong.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: show a screenshot when you create an avd

Comment: Do you have `ANDROID_HOME` in your environment variables?

Comment: post your sdk version and adt version that you are working on.

Comment: No. I don't have ANDROID_HOME in environment variable. But I have Java path set in the environment variable.

Comment: sdk version is 20 and android 4.4W

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I appreciate your help. I didn't select the image in CPU/ABI while creating the device. Now it is creating the device.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the name of the virtual device doesn't have any special characters in it and make sure you have selected a device image. You might need to download an image using the SDK Manager

Comment: I came to know that from the forum so I never used the name with space or any special character. The image comes with the ADT bundle and I installed it. The image name is "Android Wear ARM EABI v7 a System Image"

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I didn't select the image in CPU/ABI. Hopefully this will work now.